# UITableView Overlay when section index touched

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a very custom table view that actually serves as a content view, but table view was the obvious choice. I have a section index that i use to scroll the TableView - but there are no sections (well, one is there obviously). For the purpose of the user's orientation, I'd like to fade a view over the table view that is semi-transparent and shows a text in there. It should look like the overlay with the letters when scrolling the new iPod nano's section index. I don't know where i should put the code - because my view has to disappear sometime again too, and I don't really wanna use notifications. I'd init the view inside the tableview: sectionForSectionIndexTitle method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using interface builder or hardcoding it via loadView?

Comment: Well, I was thinking about hardcoding it so it doesn't clutter my storyboard...

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *overlayLabel;
```

And add the following code to your .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      self.overlayLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                                                     0.0f,
                                                                     self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                                                      self.tableView.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
      overlayLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      overlayLabel.alpha = .5f;
      overlayLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
      overlayLabel.text = @"Some text";
    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      [self.tableView addSubview:overlayLabel];
    }

    - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
      [overlayLabel removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i've been so far already. I add a SubView with Label and lay it over. Then I add an UIGestureRecognizer to touches on the UITableViewIndex. My problem now is, that in ViewDidLoad the UITableViewIndex is obviously not init yet, so the for routine that catches the UItableViewIndex from self.view.subviews is not present at that moment. Ideas? I could post some code if that helps...